# Returning axios data is undefined

Tags: node.js, electron, axios

I am trying to grab json data from a pastebin link and serve it as a popup in my electron app, but when trying to return a axios request data, it comes up undefined, also the console.log gets executed earlier than the .then for some reason, I think this has something to do with the request being async, but I haven't found a way to wait for the .then.

Code:

```
function grabPopup(fetchurl) {
  axios
    .get(fetchurl)
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
      //console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    });
}

console.log(grabPopup("https://pastebin.com/raw/0L1erTs1"));
```

The console output:

```
undefined
{ title: 'Test', message: 'Test2' }
```

Comment: Read that, didn't help me out, but thanks for linking it!

Comment: How can that didn't help you, it's exactly your problem. Of course grabPopup doesn't return anything, first of all you're not doing: `return axios`, and even if you do, it will return a `Promise` not the result. The `console.log` will always be executed earlier that the `.then` because that's how asynchronous execution works. You should reread the other question, and learn how asynchronous function work in javascript.

Comment: I'm learning asynchrounous functions now which is the reason I'm doing this project, I've read the entire thing, tried different ways of resolving the issue and it didnt work, so either I don't understand the article correctly OR The answer isnt there.

Comment: `grabPopup` miss the `return` statement

Comment: *either I don't understand the article correctly OR The answer isnt there* - the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `grabPopup` is that it isn't expose underlying promise, it should be:

```
function grabPopup(fetchurl) {
  return axios.get(fetchurl)...
}
```

This is special case of [this popular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). There is no way to access the result synchronously because the function is **a**synchronous.

It should be:

```
grabPopup("https://pastebin.com/raw/0L1erTs1")).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Well, I've tried a few iterations of the code, for some reason this code still doesn't work, I now understand what was being said about the return statement but it will still return undefined, [link](https://pastebin.com/ngbcdEQZ) here is the complete code of my project I'm starting to think I have a bigger mistake in my code. Thanks a lot for the effort you put in though!
Edit: I'm a complete idiot and fixed it, Thanks a lot for the articles and the effort again everyone!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, your code seems ok in this regard.